# (iPhone iOS 4) Better way to make a semitransparent view sliding from bottom

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4

What is the recommended way to creating the following.

A semitransparent view sliding from the bottom (like an UIActionSheet), as tall as I needed (e.g. half screen height). (Not a modal view, because this cannot be transparent, and fill entire iPhone screen.)

In this semitransparent view I set 4 UIButton that acts on the parent, background view. For example, if user clic on a UIButton a UIImageView on the background is hidden.

Now I had a HelpViewController (xib + h + m) as a subclass of UIViewController, a UIButton showHelp on the background view, and an action in background controller

```
 - (IBAction)showHelp:(id)sender {
     HelpViewController *sampleView = [[[HelpViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
     [self.view addSubview:sampleView.view];
 }
```

Should I go ahead on this road?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have created the HelpViewController that's fine now you just need to do some animation kind of staff in which the view will come from botton to up, you need to give the hight and the opacity so that that view will became a transparant view.